# How do I get the id of a mentioned user in a discord.py message?

Tags: python, bots, discord

I'm making a discord bot with discord.py. How do I get the ID of a user mentioned in a message?

For example, if someone types  `Hello @user`

The bot would detect the `@user` and find the id of that user.

Comment: You should really read the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message

Comment: Yeah, I already did it but i didnt understand what it says about mentions.

Comment: Probably something like `ctx.message.mentions[0].id` works (if it's only 1 mention). Otherwise just iterate over the mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `message` object has a `message.mentions` field that is an array of type `Member`. [Members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) have an `id` field which is equivalent to `User.id`. To get the id of a mentioned member:

```
message.mentions[0].id
```

If no one's been mentioned, the array will be empty. It's also worth noting that it's not in any particular order, so if multiple users have been mentioned the first index won't necessarily correspond to the first mention.